# Which is faster: (i == 0) or (i < 1)

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, actionscript, boolean

I recently heard that:

```
//This:
val1 * 0.5;
//Is faster than this:
val1 / 2;
```

So I wonder if there is anything else like that, and so I ask:

```
var val1:uint = 0;
//Is This:
if (val1 == 0)
//faster than this?:
if (val1 < 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? Whichever you do, the compiler will optimise it on whatever platform you are currently compiling on.

If you need to check if it's 0, use `(i == 0)`, if you want to know if it's less than zero, use that one instead. Write what you would read out loud.

Tiny things like this won't make anything faster, and you should be worried about readability and clean design rather than which tiny operation is faster.

And even if it doesn't do any logical changes, chances are on your platform, both will perform in one CPU cycle.

Comment: Will a compiler turn a divisive expression into a multiplicative one (if possible) if it "thinks" it will help performance?